# What is the time complexity of the first function?

Tags: c, time-complexity

```
static void ListInsert(List l, int value);

List findShortestSublist(List l, int start, int end) {
    Node curr = l -> first;
    Node startNode = NULL;

    List shortest = ListNew();

    while (curr != NULL) {
        if (curr -> value == start) {
            startNode = curr;
        }

        if (curr -> value == end) {
            if (startNode != NULL) {
                Node curr2 = startNode;
                while (curr2 != curr) {
                    ListInsert(shortest, curr2 -> value);
                    curr2 = curr2 -> next;
                }
                ListInsert(shortest, curr -> value);
                return shortest;
            }
        }
        curr = curr -> next;
    }

    return shortest;
}

static void ListInsert(List l, int value) {
    // Inserting List function that was used.
    Node n = newNode(value);
    if (l -> first == NULL) {
        l -> first = n;
        l -> last = n;
    } else {
        l -> last -> next = n;
        l -> last = n;
    }
}
```

Struggling to figure out the time complexity of findShortestSublist() I feel like it is a O(n^2) because it is a nested loop but it could also be O(n). The purpose of this function is to find the shortest sublist from a linked list.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms) to figure it out? Just because it's a nested loop doesn't make it n^2. Because it could also be O(n*log(n))

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? The name suggests it's looking for the shortest sublist starting with value start and ending with value end, but it looks to me like it returns the first shortest list found so far as soon as it encounters end. Do you know there aren't more end value later on in the list? The time complexity is O(n) provided ListInsert() doesn't need to read through the list to append a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

The O complexity of your function is `O(2n)` because in the worst case you will browse your list twice.

One time to find the end node and one more time to insert the item.

NOTE: it would have been `O(n^2)` in the case you had browsed the whole list for each items in the main list. But this is not the case here ..